# How to export answers to Python

Tags: python, excel

{PYTHON} I made a random passwords generator, however I want to store the passwords as well as the websites the passwords are for in an excel file.

I tried xlsxwriter which didn't seem to work.

```
import string

print ('Welcome to the Random Password generator!')

website = input('\nWebsite Name: ')
length = int(input('\nLength of the Password in Numbers: '))
all = string.punctuation + string.digits + string.ascii_letters

temp = random.sample(all,length)
password = "".join(temp)
all = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

password = "".join(random.sample(all,length))

print(password)
print('\nThanks for Choosing Us :)')
```

This is the code for the password generator

Comment: Including a minimal example of the code that didn't work will help get an answer

Answer (score 0):

```py
import string
import random
def test(website,length):
    print ('Welcome to the Random Password generator!')

    website = website
    length = length
    all = string.punctuation + string.digits + string.ascii_letters

    temp = random.sample(all,length)
    password = "".join(temp)
    all = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation

    password = "".join(random.sample(all,length))

    print(password)
    print('\nThanks for Choosing Us :)')
    return website,password
import csv
with open('file_output.csv','a') as file:
    wr=csv.writer(file)
    wr.writerow(test('google',4))
```